# PyQt5 and Wayland. A gtk-layer-shell python module for Qt5?

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, wayland

I have some python applications using the Qt5 libs I want to port/use under Wayland/wlroots. I have searched for documentation everywhere but I haven't found really nothing, apart about compositors. With the Gtk3 libs very useful is the module gtk-layer-shell for wlroots, but I cannot use it with a pyqt5 window, obviously.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What aspects are you referring to? As far as I know, a standard Qt program that used to work with X, will work in the same way with Wayland (provided that the related qt plugin is installed).

Comment: For example, this piece of code "GtkLayerShell.set_margin(window, GtkLayerShell.Edge.TOP, 10)" does appropriate things under wayland.